# install sshd using cygwin

Tags: cygwin, sshd

I want to use cygwin to install sshd in windows. But when I start the sshd service, it says:

```
The CYGWIN sshd service is starting.
The CYGWIN sshd service could not be started.
The service did not report an error.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.
```

And the `sshd.log` says:

```
Permissions 0660 for '/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

So how to deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure only the cyg_server user can access those keys.

```
chown cyg_server /etc/ssh*
chmod 600 /etc/ssh*
```

Those commands do just that, and will allow your sshd to run correctly.

Comment: I am not sure how to access the sshd.log file (`cat /var/log/sshd.log` returns blank, even my `ls` returns blank?), but I applied the two commands you stated and still cannot connect. Any idea?

Comment: Ok if I `print /var/log/sshd.log` it returns the following: `Unable to initialize device PRN` .

Comment: Hopefully someone else can be more helpful...  It took a lot of effort to actually get this going, and I only managed on one install of W7.  Are you following a guide to set this up?

Comment: Yep first I followed a Youtube video and then started on two blogs after that didn't work. My computer is a bit old; I start a new job Monday and will retry when they supply me with a new PC.

Answer (score 4):

My /var/log/sshd.log had this in the end:

```
Disabling protocol version 2. Could not load host key
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
/var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.
/var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.
/var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.
/var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.
```

Looking at /var i saw this:

```
$ ls /var -All
total 0
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 xxxx       None 0 Dec  8 15:59 cache
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 cyg_server root 0 Dec  8 16:21 empty
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 xxxx       None 0 Dec  8 15:58 lib
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 xxxx       None 0 Dec  8 16:27 log
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 xxxx       None 0 Dec  8 15:48 run
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 xxxx       None 0 Dec  8 15:48 tmp
```

So i just did `chmod 600 /var/empty` and that fixed it!